# Kubernetes expose ingress resource (API object) with load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster on amazon ews on which I intend to run multiple applications.

I have multiple services which make up one such application and I want to expose them to the internet using an amazon load balancer (elb). I want to use the ELB because I don't want to use port 80 directly as many applications share this port and I want each one of them to define their ingress resource independent of others.

I read about kubernetes ingress resources and thought that is exactly what I'm looking for. However I didn't manage to expose it through a service with load balancer. Now when I read the documentation Services are meant to expose pods but an ingress is:

> An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.

Is what I'm trying to do possible or did I not grasp some concept and trying to do something impossible or wrong?

---

My code:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  labels:
    id: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/devices
        backend:
          serviceName: device-management
          servicePort: 3001
      - path: /api/datasources
        backend:
          serviceName: data-acquisition
          servicePort: 3001
      - path: /auth,/account,/api/tenants,/api/users
        backend:
          serviceName: device-management
          servicePort: 3001
## TODO: Find out how to add subdomain entry for auth.domain and s3.domain 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress
  labels:
    id: ingress
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    id: ingress
```

Output from `kubectl describe service ingress` contains

> Endpoints:  none

Comment: I've applied successfully configuration you provided.
No problems detected.
It looks like an environment problem. What kind of installation it is? Is your cluster  created with Kops using --cloud--providerer and --cloud-config?

Comment: Errata. Proper parameters:  --cloud-provider and --cloud-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I didn't install an ingress controller. The documentation states:

> You need an Ingress controller to satisfy an Ingress, simply creating the resource will have no effect.

The ingress controller creates an nginx pod and a service (load balancer) which will then implement the rules described in all ingress resources. The [installation guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws) gives further information on how to install it on different platforms.

The ingress controller replaces the service which I desribed above and implements all ingress resources desribed in the cluster.